# Windows 2008 Audit - Acess Request Information

Tags: windows-server-2008, audit

I'm auditing some folders in a Windows 2008 R2 server and I have a "Success Audit" entry in the Security Event Log with the following "Access Request Information":

```
 Access Request Information:
                         Accesses:    %%1537

                         Access Mask:    0x10000
```

I'm not sure what type of access "%%1537" is. 
What this Access Request Information means to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1537 = %%1537 = DELETE

I used this blog to help me

http://my.opera.com/Lee_Harvey/blog/2008/10/14/microsoft-windows-security-audit-event-accesses-ids

Hope that answer your question